# Where are loopback users stored?

Tags: postgresql, loopbackjs

I am using Loopback. By default, it has a Users API. I am using postgres via [loopback-connector-postgresql](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector-postgresql).

Following the first two pieces of code on [this guide](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Registering+users), I am able to create users but I can't figure out how to view the users.

Firstly, when I try to get all users under `/explorer` route. I am receiving `401 Authorization Required`. I can't find my `User` data in my postgres db either. I checked all databases and tables and found nothing referring to `User`. Where are my users being persisted to?

I also modified `model-config.json` for `User` to see if I can get access:

```
"User": {
  "dataSource": "mydb",
  "public": true
}
...
```

but to no luck.

Answer (score 2):

Based on loopback docs you can specify where memory data must be stored in server/datasources.json like this:

```
  "db": {
    "name": "db",
    "connector": "memory",
    "file": "mydata.json"
  }
```

For more information you can read :
https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Memory+connector

Notic:

> The memory connector is designed for development and testing of a
>   single-process application without setting up a database. It cannot be
>   used in a cluster as the worker processes will have their own isolated
>   data not shared in the cluster. You can persist data between
>   application restarts using the file property. See Data persistence for
>   more information.

For view or manage users you must be create new model and extend it from loopback default User model then assign your postgresql connector for this model in server/model-config.json.
next register new user then it will save in your postgresql database.

Or change User model dataSource to your postgresql in  server/model-config.json like this:

```
 "User": {
    "dataSource": "MongoDB"
  }
```

Be aware changing this is observable after the first insert in the Users model.

see [this project](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-getting-started-intermediate/blob/master/common/models/reviewer.json) that you can learn how to config it.

Answer (score 0):

With your modification on model-config.json, Users are stored inside your database.

To get a list of all users remotely, you need to use the built-in [User REST API](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/User+REST+API).

There is a method `GET users/` that could do what you are looking for, except permission is `Deny` by default.

Since, you cannot modify built-in REST API, you need to create a model myUser that extends User.

Then, using the strongloop command line, add and ACL to GRANT `GET myUser` endpoint to `$everyone` for instance.

For testing, you can grant access to $everyone but in production you should not allow users to retrieve a list of all the users in the database.